# Experience with anti-keyloggers?

Tags: anti-virus, malware, keylogger

Does anyone have any experiences with anti-keyloggers?  I have been looking at [Zemana](http://www.zemana.com/) and it looks good to me.

Comment: A quick look at the page makes no mention of hardware keyloggers... do they make you type one real & then one fake keystroke, all the time?

Answer (score 6):

The fact that they say block all unknown threats makes me believe they are a load of bull. Pardon my American. I would say just run any good program like Malwarebytes and just do the standard safety stuff like don't load attachments that are fishy. If you are so worried about keyloggers load up a linux livecd and use that.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer would be not enter sensitive information (like logging into your bank account) when you aren't on a trusted computer. Library's, friends computers, public terminals, etc. Those would be the most vulnerable.